# Interact angularjs with jquery-ui datepicker

Tags: angularjs

Is there any way to run an angularjs script when datepicker onSelect method called?

Thanks

Comment: Do you have a working example that you need help with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course it is possible. You could instantiate the datepicker inside the controller.

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="DatePickerModule">
<div ng-controller="DatePickerController">
<input id="dateField" />
</div>
</body>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 angular.module('DatePickerModule', [])
  .controller('DatePickerController', function() {
   $('#dateField').datepicker();
  });
</script>
</html>
```

EDIT: 
If you would like to use a directive:

```html
<html>
<head>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="DatePickerApp">
 <div>
  <input id="dateField" myDirective />
 </div>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.13/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
 angular.module('DatePickerApp', [])
   .directive('mydirective', function() {
     return {
       restrict: 'A',
       link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
           $(function(){
               element.datepicker({
                   onSelect: function() {
                       alert("Selected");
                   }
               });
           });
       }
   } 
  });
 
</script>
</html>
```